# Management function in Django app complains it needs "handle()" function even though it has one

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I am trying to write a very simple management function that checks the timestamps of instances of the "Data" model via a Cronjob and deletes the ones older than 14 days. My current function looks like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = 'Delete data instances older than 14 days'

    def add_argument(self):
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=14)
        to_delete = Data.objects.filter(timestamp__lt=time_threshold)
        for instance in to_delete:
            instance.delete()
```

Something must be wrong with this command, as I get a complaint:

```
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseCommand must provide a handle() method
```

There is a handle method in the above - where is the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem after adding add_arguement function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was calling `super` in the subclass. When you do that, you call the super class's handle function, which complains that it needs to be overridden. Ugh. Dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - check your indenting.  The def handle() must be a function declared in your command subclass.  If it's outdented, you're going to get the error because -- in fact -- your handle() function doesn't exist at the right lexical level.